# How to normalize this MySQL table

Tags: mysql

before it was

table '**subscribers**':

```
id | mail            | service (comma separated)
-----------------------------------------------
1  | name1@gmail.com | TV, Internet 
2  | name2@gmail.com | Cloud, Internet 
3  | name3@gmail.com | Phone, Cloud
```

table '**messages**' contains:

```
id | title      | message               | service (comma separated)
------------------------------------------------------
1  | Disruption | TV services offline   | TV
2  | Maintenace | All services offline  | TV, Internet, Cloud 
3  | Disruption | Some services offline | TV, Internet
```

Is this the right way to normalize this?

**table_subscriber**

```
sub_id | mail
-----------------------------------------------
1      | name1@gmail.com 
2      | name2@gmail.com 
3      | name3@gmail.com
```

**table_messages**

```
message_id | title   | text
-----------------------------------------------
1          | Disruption | ...
2          | Maintenace | All services offline
3          | Disruption | Some services offline
```

**table_services**

```
service_id | title
-----------------------------------------------
1          | TV
2          | Internet
3          | Phone
```

**table_subscriber_and_services**

Subscriber can sub to multiple services

```
sub_id | service_id
---------------------
1       | 1
1       | 2
```

**table_messages_and_services**

Messages can refer to multiple services

```
message_id | service_id
---------------------
1          | 1
1          | 2
```

Comment: You didn't show the entire junction tables, but yes, at a glance this looks completely spot on.  The basic idea is to reduce the repetition of your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your schema looks good and follows 1NF, 2NF & 3NF.

Now you need table to collect all information, somethink like: **journal**:

```
id | sub_id | service_id | message_id
--------------------------------------
1  |      1 |          1 |          2
2  |      1 |          2 |          3
```

And now you can run query like:

```
SELECT
  subscriber.mail, service.title, message.title, message.text
FROM journal j
JOIN table_subscriber subscriber USING (sub_id)
JOIN table_services service USING (service_id)
JOIN table_messages message USING (message_id)
```

to receive all related information.